# wpf Validation.ErrorTemplate show tooltip on focus

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

Currently, my TextBox implements ErrorTemplate, which shows in the top right hand corner small rectangle, where upon mouse over to this object, tooltip with error message is showed. Here is how it is set up:

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationTooltipTemplate">
            <Grid x:Name="myHolder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                <Border Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="3" Height="3"/>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="Holder"/>
                <Border BorderBrush="{telerik1:Windows8Resource ResourceKey=ValidationBrush}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="{StaticResource ValidationTooltip_CornerRadius}"/>
                <Path Data="M0,2 L5,2 5,7 Z" Fill="{telerik1:Windows8Resource ResourceKey=ValidationBrush}" Width="7" Height="7" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip x:Name="PART_ToolTip"
                    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}"
                    Template="{StaticResource ErrorTooltipTemplate}"
                    Placement="Right"
                             />
                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTooltipTemplate" TargetType="ToolTip">
            <Grid x:Name="RootVisual" HorizontalAlignment="Right" RenderTransformOrigin="0 0" Opacity="0" Margin="5 0">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OpenStates">
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                            <VisualTransition To="Open" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="xform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <BackEase Amplitude=".3" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualTransition>
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Open">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="xform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="xform" X="-25"/>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <Grid>
                    <Path
                    Width="4"
                    Height="8"
                    Data="M4,0 L0,4 4,8Z"
                    Stretch="None"
                    Fill="{telerik1:Windows8Resource ResourceKey=ValidationBrush}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Border Background="{telerik1:Windows8Resource ResourceKey=ValidationBrush}" Margin="4 0 0 0" Padding="1">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ErrorContent}" TextBlock.Foreground="{telerik1:Windows8Resource ResourceKey=MainBrush}" Margin="4 2"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ContentControl/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

What I am trying to do, is to force to show tooltip once textbox gets focus (not on mouse over). I was trying to somehow trigger tooltip with setters (e.g. when **myHolder** is visible, but with no luck.

How can I trigger my error validation (how to show tooltip) immediately when the control gets focus?